# Why "deformation retracts to" instead of "deformationally retracts to"?

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation

First, correct me if I'm wrong: I grammatically understand "X deformation retracts to Y" as "X(subject) deformation(adverbial) retracts to(verb) Y(object)". But I just don't understand why we don't use "*deformationally* retracts to" instead, which in a sense looks more grammatically orthodox as "deformationally" looks more like an adverbial than "deformation" does?

Comment: The verb "deformation retract" is probably seen as a single word ("deformationretract"), even though there is a space in there. But I dunno.

Comment: I get the impression that, since "deformation retraction" is thought of as a single noun, it gets turned into a single verb: "deformation retract".

Comment: @Arthur I have to admit it's grammatically weird, given that it is a scientific terminology rather than an informally made up slang.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs about when does this concept first appear? I want to do some search on its etymology if possible. Quite interesting.

Comment: As Moe Hirsch put it, "In mathematics, a 'red herring' is in general neither red nor a herring'." I don't remember for certain the term to which he was applying the analogy; if memory serves it was "open covering" (which is neither open, nor a covering in the sense of covering spaces), but could have been, e.g., "manifold with boundary" (which is not a manifold).

Comment: Grammatically, you're absolutely right. The problem is that many of us are too lazy to speak an extra syllable for the sake of grammar.  If I wanted to be grammatically correct, I might say "retracts by deformation" since that seems to express more clearly what's happening geometrically.

Comment: Also: the term has some German scent. In German it's perfectly legit to say Deformationsretrakt (as a word) and deformationsretrahieren (related verb) - so as you say, it would be nice to have a look at the etimology. Wikipedia quotes a French article from 1931, but maybe the Germans used the term a lot later on? No idea.